# Beautiful, simple proofs worthy of writing on this beautiful glass door

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics

What are some of the more beautiful proofs you know? I am measuring beauty in two dimensions -- first, how conceptually elegant is it and second, how aesthetically pleasing is it.

Context: 
I work at a econ consulting firm. We're mostly math majors or very quantitative econ majors. A buddy and I are trying to decide what to write on the glass door to the office we share. Currently it has a graph of quality of Brad Pitt's movies against how frequently he was shirtless in that movie. Time to upgrade that...

Comment: Proof of Pythagoras theorem by dividing a right triangle by an altitude using similar triangles?

Comment: Are you looking for a beautiful picture of mathematics, or for a beautiful proof? One can occasionally find examples of proofs which can be expressed by pictures alone ("proofs without words") but they're decidedly the exception.

Comment: For your purposes, something "visual" does seem especially appropriate. Going with the Pythagorean theorem suggestion, you might look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803/what-is-the-most-elegant-proof-of-the-pythagorean-theorem) MSE thread.

Comment: @Semiclassical -- I think either is acceptable! If appropriate, I may try to just 'fluff out' a given proof with illustrations.

Comment: Some inspiration might be found in [this very relevant thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words)

Comment: I think perhaps you meant "aesthetically" and not "ascetically."

Comment: @Bey -- Yikes. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I think you should post a picture of the Brad Pitt door so we know what we're working with. =)

Comment: Remember to leave a tiny margin near the edge of the door for future proofs of significant number theory theorems.

Comment: @Vincent alas I just erased it a few minutes ago. Some clients are coming by today and I was told that they may not find it as funny as we do :)

Comment: You can write this in your door: $\displaystyle{\large{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\pi} + 1 = 0}$.

Comment: Another one for your door: $\displaystyle{\large\not\exists\ p, q \in {\mathbb Z}\ \mid\ \,\sqrt{\,2\,}\, = {p \over q}}$.

Comment: While this Question has garnered an enthusiastic response, it seems appropriate for Community Wiki treatment (since multiple "right" answers are invited).

Comment: @Craig please let us know later which one have you chosen.

Comment: @user153012 So we settled on a couple! (It's a big door). Euler's identity, the Gaussian integral, and the nice picture-proof that vincent posted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Barak beat me to my #1 choice. This would be second:

[image]

Comment: Well this one's actually much prettier with all the colors and everything (would fit perfectly on that door next to Brad Pitt).

Comment: It's also slightly more accessible for those less mathematically inclined than Euler's Identity (though I certainly like that better).

Comment: Well check this out: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/728239/131263... It's an answer to a similar question (well, more or less identical as a matter of fact). Back then I answered with the answer given here by @paw88789.

Comment: I actually like this proof better than the other.

Answer (score 12):

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ *[Geometric Explanation of the Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Geometric_explanation)*

---

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ [image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ [*Proof that* $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697629)

Comment: Wow this is amazing!

Comment: Now try drawing the proof for $(a+b)^4$ :-)

Comment: This is very good. If I need to explain the binomial theorem to an alien, I shall use this! :)

Answer (score 10):

**Cosines and Sines Around the Unit Circle**

[image: Unit Circle Angles]

**Trigonometric Angle Sum and Difference**

[image: Trig Angle Sum and Difference]

Answer (score 9):

For me, it's [Conway's inverse proof](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/conway.shtml) of the Morley equilateral triangle:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I tried to find problems from different areas. My five suggestions are.

**Sophomore' dream.** The formula for the problem is: 
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 x^{-x}\,dx &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}\end{align}$$
You can find facts about the problem and the proof of it at [*Sophomore's dream*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) wikipedia article.

**Bretschneider's formula.** This is an expression for the area of a general convex quadrilateral.
$$K = \sqrt {(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d) - abcd  \cdot \cos^2 \left(\frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}\right)}$$
It is the generalization of [*Brahmagupta theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta_theorem) and [*Henon's formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). You can find the proof at [*Bretschneider's formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula) wiki article.

**Feuerbach's circle.**  It is a circle that can be constructed for any given triangle.

[image]

It is also named *nine-point circle* because it passes through nine significant concyclic points defined from the triangle. Find more at [*Nine-point circle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle) wiki article.

**Taxicab numbers.** If you want a funny story and numbers on the door.

> I remember once going to see him when he was lying ill at Putney. I
>   had ridden in taxi-cab No. 1729, and remarked that the number seemed
>   to be rather a dull one, and that I hoped it was not an unfavourable
>   omen. "No", he replied, "it is a very interesting number; it is the
>   smallest number expressible as the sum of two [positive] cubes in two
>   different ways.

$$1729 = 1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3$$
More details about the story and list of numbers at [*Taxicab number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number) and [*1729*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_%28number%29) wiki articles. Also [*Ramanujan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan)'s wikipedia page could be interesting.

**Monty Hall problem.** Or a door-within-doors.

> Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three
>   doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a
>   door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors,
>   opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you,
>   "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch
>   your choice?

[image]

More details at [*Monty Hall problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) wikipage.

Answer (score 7):

I'm fond of Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes: For any finite set $S=\{p_1, p_2,\dots, p_k\}$ of prime numbers, let $N=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot\cdots\cdot p_k+1$.  Then $N$ isn't divisible by any prime in $S$.  Hence it is divisible by some other prime.  Hence the set $S$ does not include all primes.  Thus there must be infinitely many primes.

Comment: For an esoteric accompaniment to that, one could write down Euler's product formula of the Riemann zeta function nearby: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p\in\,\text{primes}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}.$$ (If there were finitely many primes, what would be true of the harmonic series?)

Comment: For clarity's sake, it's also possibly that _N_ itself is prime... but then it's also not in _S_, hence etc. etc.

Comment: @Dancrumb: Even if $N$ is prime, it is divisible by itself, and so I think the above is still ok even in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Proof of [Euler's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity): $$e^{\pi{i}}+1=0$$

BTW, your question is more or less a copy of ["Simple" beautiful math proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/728223/131263), so you might wanna check it out too. There's some great colorful stuff there, my answer being somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few visual proofs that

$$\text{arctan}(1) + \text{arctan}(2) + \text{arctan}(3) = \pi$$

[One by user KennyTM](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/197417/97045):

[image: Visual Proof 1]

---

[More by user dldarek](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/272250/97045):

[image: Visual Proof 2]

---

I think the lattice nature of the proofs would look nice on a door.

Comment: Don't forget to follow the links to their posts, the original posts should have priority for votes.

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions:

$1$. The proof for the Gaussian integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2} \mathrm dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

$2$. The proof for Euler's solution to the Basel problem

$$\frac {\ \ \pi^2}6=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\frac 1{1^2}+\frac 1{2^2}+\frac 1{3^2}+\frac 1{4^2}+\cdots+\frac 1{n^2}+\cdots$$

$3$. The proof for Wallis' product
$$\frac \pi 2=\frac 21 \cdot \frac 23\cdot \frac43\cdot\frac45\cdot\frac65\cdot\frac67\cdots $$

From the above it is interesting to note how $\pi^{\frac 12}$, $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ can be computed using an integral, an infinite product, and an infinite sum respectively.

Perhaps something more relevant for a glass door would the equations written on the glass window by John Nash (Russell Crowe) in the movie "A Beautiful Mind"!

Answer (score 5):

The rudimentary differential equation proof of Euler's formula in the complex plane $e^{i \pi}=-1$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. 
First, via $\frac{d}{d\theta}$,

$$e^{i\theta}=f(\theta)+ig(\theta) \implies ie^{i\theta}=f^{\prime}(\theta)+ig^{\prime}(\theta)=if(\theta)-g(\theta).$$

Comparing real and imaginary parts, $f(\theta)=g^{\prime}(\theta)$ and $f^{\prime}(\theta)=-g(\theta)$ which implies

$$f^{\prime \prime}(\theta)+f(\theta)=0 \implies f(\theta)=\cos(\theta),\: g(\theta)=\sin(\theta).$$

Evaluating at $\theta=\pi$, gives $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: If you are going to make the assumption that $\frac{d}{d\theta} e^{i\theta} = ie^{i\theta}$ then Euler's result follows immediately from the fact that multiplication by $i$ is a quarter angle rotation in the complex plane, and motion at a quarter angle to position is a circle.

Answer (score 5):

The proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is pretty simple and satisfying, I think. It's a very easy result to achieve, but the proof is very elegant and has some nice symmetry.

Assume $\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$ with p and q relatively prime (totally simplified).

$2q^2 = p^2$

$p^2$ is even

the square of an odd number is odd, so $p$ must be even. Let $p=2r$

$2q^2=4r^2$

$q^2=2r^2$

$q^2$ is even

the square of an odd number is odd, so $q$ must be even

contradiction: $p$ and $q$ are both even, so they are not relatively prime. $\sqrt{2}$ must be irrational.

Answer (score 5):

The classification of finite simple groups -- so there would finally be a single reference that could be given for this important result. ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Calculus**

The proof that [$\frac{22}{7} > \pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80).

$$ \begin {align*} 0 &< \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac {x^4 \left( 1 - x \right)^4}{1 + x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\&= \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac {x^4 - 4x^5 + 6x^6 - 4x^7 + x^8}{1 + x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\&= \frac {22}{7} - \pi. \end {align*} $$

**Geometry**

The Pythagorean Theorem.

[image: pythag]

**Algebra**

Proof that $ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 = \left( \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \right)^2 $: a proof without words.

[image: Proof that the sum of the cubes is the square of the sum]

**Number Theory**

1. [Deriving Binet's Formula](http://planetmath.org/derivationofbinetformula).
2. Finding two irrationals $x,y$ such that $x^y$ is rational. If $x=y=\sqrt2$ is an example, then we are done; otherwise $\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ is irrational, in which case taking $x=\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}$ and $y=\sqrt2$ gives us: $$\left(\sqrt2^{\sqrt2}\right)^{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2^{\sqrt2\sqrt2}=\sqrt2^2=2.\qquad\square$$

**Combinatorics**

[Binomial coefficients equal alternating sum of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/combinatorial-proof-that-binomial-coefficients-are-given-by-alternating-sums-of) $-$ see *leonbloy*'s answer.

[image: Visual proof]

On the left, you have the alternating sum as an inclusion-exclusion of squares: the total sum is the number of coloured cells.

On the right, you have those L shaped shapes rearranged in the top left of a 6x6 grid.
If you think of each cell as a coordinate $(x_1,x_2)$ that gives two elements chosen from the set $\{1, 2 \cdots 6\}$, it's seen that the elements are choosen  with $ x_2 > x_1$, what corresponds to a combination (no repetition, and no order).

The others are well known, but, just for the sake of completeness...

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} k^2 = {n+1 \choose 2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \; k = \frac{(n+1) \; n}{2}$$

---

As a side note, [this link is excellent](http://www.mathpath.org/proof/proof.great.htm) if you want to find your own and decide if proofs you see are actually nice.

Also, if you want to see a list of awesome proofs without words, [see here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Proofs_without_words).

[image: Visual proof 2]

Comment: Proof that $22/7$ exceeds $\pi$ is really a nice one.

Answer (score 3):

A still image from the top-voted entry at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words along with the equation it proves, $1+2+\cdots+(n-1)={n\choose2}$, could be good.  (Note: the entry there was originally just a still.  Personally I find the animation a little unpleasant, but that may just be me.)

Added later:  The original version of this proof without words, which appeared in "A Discrete Look at $1+2+\cdots+n$" by Loren Larson, can be found at http://www.matem.unam.mx/~rod/teaching/mac/larson-discrete_look_gauss_series.pdf (see Figure 7 there).

Answer (score 2):

Euler's identity *in matrix form* ([***link***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773359/eulers-identity-in-matrix-form) for proof):

$$ \color{#10a}{\large{e^{i \, \mathbf{\Pi}} + \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{0}} }$$

Cheers!

Comment: Already suggested about 3 hours ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/911068/131263)

Comment: Not in matrix form I'm afraid @barakmanos.

Comment: Oh... got it :)

Comment: But the matrix form is just a special case of continuous functional calculus...

Comment: And? This is a door.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the interpolation theorem three steps which seems redundant yields an amazing result 
Or the proof for the gamma function at 1/2 gives pi otherwise known as
 (1/2)!=π

EDIT:as noted in the comments square root of pi  is actually the value of of the gammq function at 1/2 which is defined for (n-1)!

Comment: You are wrong. $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$, on the other hand $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for positive integers, so "$(1/2)!$" could be $\Gamma(3/2)=\sqrt{\pi}/2$, but we dont use factorial notation for nonintegral numbers. That is one of the reason why we introduce Gamma function! Bytheway the idea is good, it is really an *amazing result*!

Comment: Oops sorry you are right  I will add an edit  right away